Inverse of the Riemann Mapping Theorem
The statement of the Riemann Mapping Theorem says that there exists a mapping (with some properties) that can transform any 'simply connected domain' to the unit disc.
Is there an inverse for this theorem? That is, is there a general statement on the existence and properties of mappings that can transform the unit disc to any simply connected domain in the complex plane?
I am an Aerospace engineering graduate student, not very strong in complex analysis but I have some basic understanding. For my research I am looking for the existence of a theorem that would essentially be an inverse of the reimann theorem.

Actually, the Riemann mapping theorem asserts the existence of a biholomorphism -- a bijection that is holomorphic in both directions.  So RMT already includes the inverse you ask about.

It's "Riemann", not "Reimann"

@EricTowers aha that's true! Are there alternative statements of the Riemann Mapping theorem that do not talk about biholomorphism? How would one construct such functions. I have seen some statements that talk about conformal maps. Would any conformal map transform the unit disc to a simply connected domain?

@AtharvaAalok it only talks about existence but construction can be impossible by hand.
